# How to know if a form is shown as dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there is already some property that I could use such as:

```
if (this.IsDialog)
{
    DialogResult = ...;
}
else
{
    // Do something else.
}
```

Or should I create such property *myself* and set it to `true` before showing the form as dialog?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can check to see if [`this.Modal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx) is true.

Comment: What about checking if `is CommonDialog`?

Comment: @Oded CommonDialog won't work for a user-created form shown via `ShowDialog()`

Comment: So Modal means shown as dialog? Or are there other Modal cases?

Comment: @Dil ShowDialog is the only way the framework sets modal.  It's actually checking whether or not the modal style is applied, so there are probably ways to break it if you really try, but this will work as long as you don't do anything very odd (ie: PInvoke windows api calls to change the window at runtime, etc)

Comment: Then this must be enough. Thanks.

Comment: How can we check it in wpf ?