# Determine whether a Windows Form has been opened as Modal

Tags: c#, winforms, modal-dialog

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know if a form is shown as dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105262/how-to-know-if-a-form-is-shown-as-dialog)

I have a winform that may be opened as a dialogbox, or as a regular window.
When it is opened as a regular windows I want to hide the OK cancel buttons, is there any way of checking if a winform is opened as a dialogbox or not ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Modal` property:

```
public bool Modal { get; }
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.modal.aspx